# Android WebView:How to display only part of webpage

Tags: android

In the web page,i'am using,i need to remove some parts:sidebar for example and i tried some ways to do that,but without succsess.It's always a whole page,that being displayed.I'm doing that in fragment.My code is:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.standing_fragment,null);
    WebView wv= (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView2);
    WebViewClient client=new WebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            //super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            if(isLoaded)
                return;
            isLoaded=true;
            view.loadUrl(url);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display = 'none';");
          //  wv.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementsByClassName('div.table-container')[0].style.display='none'");
        }
    };

    WebSettings settings=wv.getSettings();
    settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.setWebViewClient(client);
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.soccernews.com/teams/psg/");
    return view;
}
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this you need to remember, how webview works.
Which is some kind of embed 'browser' view. 
You can solve it like this:

1. Making your own http get request and read string response.
2. Manipulate received string response - in your case inject Javascript code
3. Load manipulated code to the web view.

To demonstrate an example I'll use [HttpRequest](http://pastebin.com/wXbqGMqR) class that I wrote to support android 22+ (since apache's package deprecated).

**Step one**: request and read String response

```
String response=new HttpRequest("http://somedomain.com").prepare().sendAndReadString();
```

**Step Two:** manipulate response before loading

```
result+="<script>onload=function(){document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display='none';}</script>";
```

**Step Three:** load it to the web view

```
wv.loadData(result, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

Simplified example for everything togather:

```
new AsyncTask<String, Void, String>(){
        protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {
            try {
                return new HttpRequest(params[0]).prepare().sendAndReadString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("***Web View - manipulated content - ERROR***", e.getMessage());
                return null;//to promote null further
            }
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result==null)return;//Error logged, don't load anything
            result=result.concat("<script>onload=function(){document.querySelector('#sidebar').style.display='none';}</script>");
            wv.loadData(result, "text/html", "UTF-8");
        }
    }.execute("http://www.soccernews.com/teams/psg/");
```